# Fan speed increased after upgrading to SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, temperature

I just replaced my Macbook Pro's Mid 2012 HDD with a Samsung 850 EVO SSD. The performance is great and I am very happy, but I noticed that the fan seems to run faster. It is not a drastic change, but it is noticeable. I have downloaded iStat Menus, the Exhaust of the fan is 2000 rpm and the Temperature is a bit over 50°. Is that normal and is there any chance I did something wrong while replacing the HDD? 
I am running Yosemite and I did a SMC reset.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Controlling the fan speed in Mac models after an SSD upgrade](https://www.sandboxgeneral.com/?p=634). Extracted from that article:

> 1. Download the app “[smcFanControl](https://www.eidac.de/?p=312)“
> 2. Install smcFanControl into your Applications folder
> 3. Open Automator
> 4. Create “New Application”
> 5. Go to Utilities > “Run Shell Script” and delete the word “Cat”
> 6. Copy the following code into the Shell Script:
> 7. `/applications/smcfancontrol.app/Contents/resources/smc -k F1Mx -w 1770`
> 8. Test the Shell Script by clicking on “Run” and your fan should stop running at full speed
> 9. Save the application to your SSD as “maxfanadjustment”
> 10. Open System Preferences, go to Users & Groups, the tab for Login Items
> 11. Click the “+” to add a new application and navigate to the Automator file you just created and add it.

Comment: Thanks! After some extended research I found out statements that 2000 rpm is actually normal for MBP 2012

Comment: @Georgi if you found references solving your question feel free to use full answer with link to references to help others with similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't download smcFanControl, infection "PUA.OSX.InstallCore" found in the .dmg file.

Comment: Can someone confirm if this is true? if so the answer above should be removed or modified.

Comment: What URL did you find the problem? It's common that some side sites get messed up / malicious downloads. Good information if we can narrow down what source to avoid. I edited the answer above since MacUpdate might not be the best place to get smcFanControl.